# 12.10 hangs on Ubuntu loading screen

Tags: installation, 12.10

been trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my Toshiba Satellite C855D. Specs are 2.7 GHz AMD with built in Radeon Graphics card. The same ISO that I am currently trying to install has been used to install Ubuntu on 2 other laptops one HP and one Toshiba. When I press the Function Keys while the screen is loading it shows me what action is being taken. The load stalls out at the message "Starting Crash Report Submission Daemon", any help troubleshooting this issue would be great.

Thank you, USAF_Hebbes

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) Does not fix this issue.

Comment: Does "Starting Crash Report Submission Daemon" finish? Is there anything that appears to the right of it? Perhaps that step actually succeeds, and the problem occurs afterwards. Also, there's a lot of suggestions [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it); you should edit your question to explain in detail everything you have tried, and what happened.

Answer (score 0):

The "Starting Crash Report Submission Daemon" would actually occur *after* the problem has occurred. (Basically, that's saying that the system recognized there's a problem and trying to report it.) What comes before that will actually be what's important to solving your issue.

Comment: Why would this mean the system has recognized a problem? The crash report submission daemon starts normally on boot *so that it is running and can report crashes as they arise*. It is a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)), after all.